# 16.04 recent install low graphics mode error

Tags: 16.04

I recently installed 16.04 on a pen drive and it keeps on coming up with a running in low graphics mode pop up and wont let me do anything. I'm not the greatest with terminal. help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I also cannot get to grub menu when I hold shift during boot it takes me to what looks like a terminal.
Also don't believe I have a user name or password.

Comment: To fix this, please follow the guide [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: At the boot screen where you choose "Try Ubuntu", please press F6, which will allow you to add boot options. Add `nomodeset` to the end of the options, and then boot into "Try Ubuntu" as usual. Does that help?

Comment: F6 doesnt seem to do anything :/, I am running the pen drive on a dell inspiron 1122 in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same infamous "Low graphics mode" issue after upgrading to 16.04 out of my curiosity from 14.* LTS. I tried installing/uninstalling graphics drivers (open source/official), configuring/reconfiguring various desktop managers, trying various previous kernels, installing/reinstalling GL/mesa drivers via `apt-get`, removing `~/.*authority`, creating `xorg.conf`, changing/fixing/blacklisting graphics kernel modules and so on, but nothing worked

Finally, I saw that `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` didn't have any greeter-session at all. So, added `greeter-session=unity-greeter` and then got the `lightdm` login page instead of flickering black screen saying "System program problem..." dialog box appearing and
disappearing every few seconds.

Then, I got into another infamous issue - login loop. For this, I switched the desktop environment to GNOME metacity as none of the other worked - Ubuntu, Unity8 Mir, Gnome Compiz, etc. Finally, I was able to login, but "system settings" was having issues - unity-control-center and gnome-control-center were crashing with SegFault.

So, I installed the latest built mesa driver from mesa-12.* sources (only half built as there was some llvm error but installed the so far stuff anyway which included
the intel drivers as I saw), and at last "system settings" opened successfully.

Comment: You faced a login loop issue since removed .Xauthority files under your profile.